# What is something that could make steel flexible through infusion?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space-warfare

I am looking to make robot parts out of steel. Parts should be bendable with the help of science. Answer should deliver permanent deformable steel parts to  facilitate fast, acrobatic movements for an assassin-type robot requiring agility in combat.

Comment: Why would a permanently deformable part sustain agility?

Comment: its an assembly of parts that shouldnt be rigid bodies. it's to facilitate fast, acrobatic movements coming from an assassin-type robot. @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica

Comment: I might be wrong, but anything which has to react fast (like race car, fighter jets, race bike) has usually a very rigid frame. It has nothing to do with permanent deformation.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica sorry but i guess i meant 'rigid bodies' in physics where it applies to objects with deformation close to zero. vehicles you mentioned should have regions meant to absorp impact. almost any utilised structures have a degree of flexibility in particular regions so that they remain resilient.  

this mech of mine, unlike vehicles where the parts should move uniformly, has its own limbs bearing different kind of stresses. one hand could be blocking a punch while the other holding a sword, etc. it's bipedal too.

Comment: So you want something that have SOME features of steel yet it's not steel because steel features come from hardening. So you don't want steel.

Comment: Steel **is** flexible and bendable by its nature. No infusion needed. Its elasticity is one of the most important properties of steel. Are you looking for how to make a spring? Or a blade?

Comment: @AlexP i think i secretly knew this except i needed a complex scientific process shot to be part of a laboratory scene. was looking to give my lead scientists something talk about how their mechs are outdated and incompatible with the real nature of an open warfare. so the parent idea was transitioning from huge, useless mechs into troops of much more agile, smaller ones. sly over brutish. i thought rethinking materials would be one step towards that.

Answer (score 3):

You want a mix of steel parts and [Shape-memory alloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape-memory_alloy).

These alloys have the unique property of returning to a previous shape when heated and/or cooled. In this case, you'd want to have two-way memory alloys that have one shape when hot and another when cold. That allows for bending and straightening the limbs of the android by heating and cooling.

The main problem I see is that cooling especially is hard to do in a split second, which is probably what you need for agile assassin droids. There are some decent ways to increase heat transfer but none at the level you want, so I would "invent" a similar alloy that changes shape when exposed to an electric current. It's not implausable that the increased energy of the electrons cause the molecular bonds to change like heat does for known shape-memory alloys and allows for much quicker and controlled movement.

I don't expect it would actually work to infuse steel with this and have the whole thing deform into many shapes, but the alloys are pretty strong by themselves, so they could form most of the android's body, with some additional steel parts for armoring/weapons. Of course, your scientists might have figured that one out too...

Comment: interesting take. but both suggestions sounds like too much energy needed for seamless movement esp when the state of the material is constantly changing--at least by how i understand it. id prefer it to be in the permanent state of flexible. maybe done with infusing an element of some kind into it. any physical force upon impact then is deflected. (or absorbed? i honestly dont know)

Answer (score 2):

#### Why not just make flexible parts out of steel?

You don't need to add anything to steel to make it flexible, intelligently designed steel parts can be flexible.

Just because something is made out of steel doesn't mean it's rigid. If you cast a massive steel thing like an engine block - sure its basically static, but you can make thin steel parts that can flex. **Flexible steel is all around you:**

This steel part is very flexible, it's probably under your sink or connecting your dishwasher:
[image]

This steel wire is very flexible;

[image]

By interspersing thin parts of steel together your robot arm could flex and morph in any way you need.

Comment: probably the route im going for. i should now figure out how to make its application on my mechs as some out-of-this-world tech. thank you though!

Comment: And springs!  Spring steel!.  Spring steel is springy.